# Array Binding with Oracle(11g) Db and c#

Tags: c#, oracle11g, binding

I'm currentlty working on a application for which  I need to insert a few thousands lines at the same time in an Oracle (11g) base(using ODP.NET). ("Bulk Insert style")

That's is why I am trying to use the Array binding technique for Oracle data base using ODP.net.

Here is my code : I get no Error while running it, but nothing happens either it runs for ever.

If anyone has an idea of where the problem could come from please tell me.

Thanks for your help.

```
 private static void AddDataTableToDataBase(DataTable tableLog)
    {
        string[] type = new string[tableLog.Rows.Count];
        DateTime[] timestamp = new DateTime[tableLog.Rows.Count];
        string[] source = new string[tableLog.Rows.Count];
        string[] appName = new string[tableLog.Rows.Count];
        string[] action = new string[tableLog.Rows.Count];
        string[] fileType = new string[tableLog.Rows.Count];
        string[] usr = new string[tableLog.Rows.Count];
        int?[] executionTime = new int?[tableLog.Rows.Count];
        string[] addMetadata = new string[tableLog.Rows.Count];
        string[] explanation = new string[tableLog.Rows.Count];


        for (int i = 0; i < tableLog.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            type[i] = tableLog.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            timestamp[i] = (DateTime)tableLog.Rows[i][1];
            source[i] = tableLog.Rows[i][2].ToString();
            appName[i] = tableLog.Rows[i][3].ToString();
            action[i] = tableLog.Rows[i][4].ToString();
            fileType[i] = tableLog.Rows[i][5].ToString();
            usr[i] = tableLog.Rows[i][6].ToString();
            int executionTimeValue; 
            if (int.TryParse(tableLog.Rows[i][7].ToString(), out executionTimeValue)) 
                executionTime[i] = executionTimeValue;

            addMetadata[i] = tableLog.Rows[i][8].ToString();
            explanation[i] = tableLog.Rows[i][9].ToString();
        }
        string OracleConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DmsConnection"].ConnectionString;
        (OracleConnectionString);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(OracleConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
                    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LOG (TYPE,TIMESTAMP,SOURCE,APPNAME,ACTION,FILETYPE,USR,EXECUTIONTIME,ADDMETADATA,EXPLANATION) VALUES (:TYPE, :TIMESTAMP, :SOURCE, :APPNAME, :ACTION, :FILETYPE, :USR, :EXECUTIONTIME, :ADDMETADATA, :EXPLANATION)";

        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter TYPE = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("TYPE", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 150, "TYPE");
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter TIMESTAMP = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("TIMESTAMP", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Date);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter SOURCE = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("SOURCE", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 150);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter APPNAME = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("APPNAME", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 150);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter ACTION = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("ACTION", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 150);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter FILETYPE = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("FILETYPE", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 150);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter USR = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("USR", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.NVarchar2, 150);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter EXECUTIONTIME = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("EXECUTIONTIME", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter ADDMETADATA = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("ADDMETADATA", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Clob);
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter EXPLANATION = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("EXPLANATION", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Clob);

        TYPE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        TIMESTAMP.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        SOURCE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        APPNAME.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        ACTION.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        FILETYPE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        USR.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        EXECUTIONTIME.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        ADDMETADATA.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        EXPLANATION.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(TYPE);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(TIMESTAMP);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(SOURCE);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(APPNAME);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ACTION);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(FILETYPE);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(USR);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(EXECUTIONTIME);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ADDMETADATA);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(EXPLANATION);

        cmd.Parameters["TYPE"].Value = type;
        cmd.Parameters["TIMESTAMP"].Value = timestamp;
        cmd.Parameters["SOURCE"].Value = source;
        cmd.Parameters["APPNAME"].Value = appName;
        cmd.Parameters["ACTION"].Value = action;
        cmd.Parameters["FILETYPE"].Value = fileType;
        cmd.Parameters["USR"].Value = usr;
        cmd.Parameters["EXECUTIONTIME"].Value = executionTime;
        cmd.Parameters["ADDMETADATA"].Value = addMetadata;
        cmd.Parameters["EXPLANATION"].Value = explanation;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Are you able to step through the code to determine which line it's getting stuck on? If you can't step through the code, then can you add some print statements?

Comment: hey Davmos thanks for your comment.
It gets stuck on the "executeNonQuey() " instruction .
I have tried many different values for the query and this one is the only one that doesn't raise an error.

Comment: OK, how many rows are you trying to insert? Perhaps it's just taking a long time. Can you try with just one row? If it still doesn't return, perhaps the table is locked & it's waiting for that lock to be released. It maybe locked by another user/process or perhaps even yourself if you've executed a previous insert or update and not commited!

Comment: Hey I tried it with only a few rows and it worked. It took around 20 sec for execution. I have an average of 4000 rows to insert every day, so I'd say that it takes around 30 minutes to add one file of logs. Is there a faster way to insert rows in an Oracle data base using a C# app ?Anyway thank you for your help davmos.

Comment: Ihave found out that what's is taking so much time is to insert Clob oracle data type. There is an internal conversion of string to Clob.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Let me know if you need any further help solving that. I think I've done it before... it was many moons ago, so I'd have to look it up ;-)

Comment: Thanks !! But I'm good I decided to truncate the strings that were too long and know it takes just a few seconds to insert all 4000 lines :)

Comment: Well done! +1 for the question You could also answer your own question... it might help someone one day. Or I could answer it if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

The code above works fine, the only problem is that I use Clob Oracle data type. The internal conversion from string to Clob takes a lot of time.

I ended up truncating the strings that were too long and now it works fine and it is really fast. (Just a few seconds to insert 4000 records).